# C# Selenium WebElement cannot be found more than once

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I want to create a frontend test and use Selenium and Chrome for it.
I am confused because the same element is found only once with the same code. But I need it in two places
Here is my Code

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".pane-container")), 50, 50).ClickAndHold().MoveByOffset(50, 50).Release().Perform();
driver.Navigate().Refresh();
Actions drawBoundingBox = new Actions(driver);
drawBoundingBox.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".pane-container"))); //NoSuchElementException
```

the driver has an implicit wait of a few seconds.
When I try to find it for the second time I get a NoSuchElementException.
*OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".pane-container"}*

When I remove the first one the second one works:

```
driver.Navigate().Refresh();
Actions drawBoundingBox = new Actions(driver);
drawBoundingBox.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".pane-container")));
```

->no Exception

Is the Element somehow blocked when first used?

Edit:
I inspected the HTML of the website. As far as I can tell, there is no relevant difference between the elements.

Element when referenced first:

```html
<div class="pane-container selected">
  <div class="mat-elevation-z2 label-options" style="transform: translate(49.9023px, 109.785px);">
    <rcv-selected-label-options _ngcontent-ftq-c196="" _nghost-ftq-c195="">
      <mat-form-field _ngcontent-ftq-c195="" class="mat-form-field label-select ng-tns-c70-4 mat-primary mat-form-field-type-mat-select mat-form-field-appearance-legacy mat-form-field-can-float mat-form-field-has-label mat-form-field-hide-placeholder mat-form-field-should-float">
        <div class="mat-form-field-wrapper ng-tns-c70-4">
          <div class="mat-form-field-flex ng-tns-c70-4">
            <!----><!---->
            <div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c70-4">
              <mat-select _ngcontent-ftq-c195="" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="none" aria-haspopup="true" required="" class="mat-select ng-tns-c87-5 ng-tns-c70-4 mat-select-required ng-star-inserted" aria-labelledby="mat-form-field-label-1 mat-select-value-5" id="mat-select-4" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false" aria-required="true" aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="false">
                <div cdk-overlay-origin="" class="mat-select-trigger ng-tns-c87-5">
                  <div class="mat-select-value ng-tns-c87-5" id="mat-select-value-5">
                    <!---->
                    <span class="mat-select-value-text ng-tns-c87-5 ng-star-inserted">
                      <span class="mat-select-min-line ng-tns-c87-5 ng-star-inserted">Klasse 1</span><!----><!---->
                    </span>
                    <!---->
                  </div>
                  <div class="mat-select-arrow-wrapper ng-tns-c87-5">
                    <div class="mat-select-arrow ng-tns-c87-5"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!---->
              </mat-select>
              <span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c70-4">
                <label class="mat-form-field-label ng-tns-c70-4 ng-star-inserted" id="mat-form-field-label-1" for="mat-select-4" aria-owns="mat-select-4">
                  <span class="ng-tns-c70-4 ng-star-inserted">Select object class</span><!----><!----><!----><span aria-hidden="true" class="mat-placeholder-required mat-form-field-required-marker ng-tns-c70-4 ng-star-inserted"> *</span><!---->
                </label>
                <!---->
              </span>
            </div>
            <!---->
          </div>
          <div class="mat-form-field-underline ng-tns-c70-4 ng-star-inserted"><span class="mat-form-field-ripple ng-tns-c70-4"></span></div>
          <!---->
          <div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper ng-tns-c70-4">
            <!---->
            <div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c70-4 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);">
              <!---->
              <div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer ng-tns-c70-4"></div>
            </div>
            <!---->
          </div>
        </div>
      </mat-form-field>
      <!---->
    </rcv-selected-label-options>
  </div>
  <svg id="SvgjsSvg1006" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.com/svgjs" viewBox="0 0 1280 1024">
    <defs id="SvgjsDefs1007"></defs>
    <g id="SvgjsG1008" class="svg-cursor" style="display: none;" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1194.5501708984375,678.3675537109375)">
      <line id="SvgjsLine1142" x1="-186.58038147138961" y1="75" x2="336.5803814713896" y2="75" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="6.975476839237056 6.975476839237056" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="6.975476839237056"></line>
      <line id="SvgjsLine1143" x1="75" y1="-186.58038147138961" x2="75" y2="336.5803814713896" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="6.975476839237056 6.975476839237056" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="6.975476839237056"></line>
      <line id="SvgjsLine1144" x1="22.68392370572208" y1="75" x2="127.31607629427792" y2="75" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="0 6.975476839237056 0" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="6.975476839237056"></line>
      <line id="SvgjsLine1145" x1="75" y1="22.68392370572208" x2="75" y2="127.31607629427792" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="0 6.975476839237056 0" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="6.975476839237056"></line>
    </g>
    <rect id="SvgjsRect1101" width="50" height="50" x="50" y="50" class="bounding-box" fill-opacity="0.4" fill="#ff0000" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="0" stroke="#ff0000"></rect>
    <g id="SvgjsG1132" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,50,50)">
      <rect id="SvgjsRect1133" width="50" height="50" class="svg_select_boundingRect svg_select_points"></rect>
      <rect id="SvgjsRect1134" width="24.4141689373297" height="24.4141689373297" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3.487738419618528" fill="#000000" x="-12.20708446866485" y="-12.20708446866485" class="svg_select_points_lt svg_select_points"></rect>
      <rect id="SvgjsRect1135" width="24.4141689373297" height="24.4141689373297" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3.487738419618528" fill="#000000" x="37.792915531335154" y="-12.20708446866485" class="svg_select_points_rt svg_select_points"></rect>
      <rect id="SvgjsRect1136" width="24.4141689373297" height="24.4141689373297" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3.487738419618528" fill="#000000" x="37.792915531335154" y="37.792915531335154" class="svg_select_points_rb svg_select_points"></rect>
      <rect id="SvgjsRect1137" width="24.4141689373297" height="24.4141689373297" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3.487738419618528" fill="#000000" x="-12.20708446866485" y="37.792915531335154" class="svg_select_points_lb svg_select_points"></rect>
      <rect id="SvgjsRect1138" width="24.4141689373297" height="24.4141689373297" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3.487738419618528" fill="#000000" x="12.79291553133515" y="-12.20708446866485" class="svg_select_points_t svg_select_points"></rect>
      <rect id="SvgjsRect1139" width="24.4141689373297" height="24.4141689373297" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3.487738419618528" fill="#000000" x="37.792915531335154" y="12.79291553133515" class="svg_select_points_r svg_select_points"></rect>
      <rect id="SvgjsRect1140" width="24.4141689373297" height="24.4141689373297" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3.487738419618528" fill="#000000" x="12.79291553133515" y="37.792915531335154" class="svg_select_points_b svg_select_points"></rect>
      <rect id="SvgjsRect1141" width="24.4141689373297" height="24.4141689373297" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3.487738419618528" fill="#000000" x="-12.20708446866485" y="12.79291553133515" class="svg_select_points_l svg_select_points"></rect>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Element when referenced second time:

```html
<div class="pane-container selected">
  <div class="mat-elevation-z2 label-options hidden" style="transform: translate(-10000px, -10000px);">
    <rcv-selected-label-options _ngcontent-rqy-c196="" _nghost-rqy-c195="">
      <mat-form-field _ngcontent-rqy-c195="" class="mat-form-field label-select ng-tns-c70-4 mat-primary mat-form-field-type-mat-select mat-form-field-appearance-legacy mat-form-field-can-float mat-form-field-has-label mat-form-field-hide-placeholder">
        <div class="mat-form-field-wrapper ng-tns-c70-4">
          <div class="mat-form-field-flex ng-tns-c70-4">
            <!----><!---->
            <div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c70-4">
              <mat-select _ngcontent-rqy-c195="" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="none" aria-haspopup="true" required="" class="mat-select ng-tns-c87-5 ng-tns-c70-4 mat-select-required mat-select-empty ng-star-inserted" aria-labelledby="mat-form-field-label-1 mat-select-value-5" id="mat-select-4" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false" aria-required="true" aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="false">
                <div cdk-overlay-origin="" class="mat-select-trigger ng-tns-c87-5">
                  <div class="mat-select-value ng-tns-c87-5" id="mat-select-value-5">
                    <span class="mat-select-placeholder mat-select-min-line ng-tns-c87-5 ng-star-inserted">Select object class</span><!----><!---->
                  </div>
                  <div class="mat-select-arrow-wrapper ng-tns-c87-5">
                    <div class="mat-select-arrow ng-tns-c87-5"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!---->
              </mat-select>
              <span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c70-4">
                <label class="mat-form-field-label ng-tns-c70-4 mat-empty mat-form-field-empty ng-star-inserted" id="mat-form-field-label-1" for="mat-select-4" aria-owns="mat-select-4">
                  <span class="ng-tns-c70-4 ng-star-inserted">Select object class</span><!----><!----><!----><span aria-hidden="true" class="mat-placeholder-required mat-form-field-required-marker ng-tns-c70-4 ng-star-inserted"> *</span><!---->
                </label>
                <!---->
              </span>
            </div>
            <!---->
          </div>
          <div class="mat-form-field-underline ng-tns-c70-4 ng-star-inserted"><span class="mat-form-field-ripple ng-tns-c70-4"></span></div>
          <!---->
          <div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper ng-tns-c70-4">
            <!---->
            <div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c70-4 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);">
              <!---->
              <div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer ng-tns-c70-4"></div>
            </div>
            <!---->
          </div>
        </div>
      </mat-form-field>
      <!---->
    </rcv-selected-label-options>
  </div>
  <svg id="SvgjsSvg1006" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.com/svgjs" viewBox="0 0 1280 1024">
    <defs id="SvgjsDefs1007"></defs>
    <g id="SvgjsG1008" class="svg-cursor" style="display: none;" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1191.0623779296875,364.4643859863281)">
      <line id="SvgjsLine1013" x1="-186.58038147138961" y1="75" x2="336.5803814713896" y2="75" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="6.975476839237056 6.975476839237056" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="6.975476839237056"></line>
      <line id="SvgjsLine1014" x1="75" y1="-186.58038147138961" x2="75" y2="336.5803814713896" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="6.975476839237056 6.975476839237056" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="6.975476839237056"></line>
      <line id="SvgjsLine1015" x1="22.68392370572208" y1="75" x2="127.31607629427792" y2="75" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="0 6.975476839237056 0" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="6.975476839237056"></line>
      <line id="SvgjsLine1016" x1="75" y1="22.68392370572208" x2="75" y2="127.31607629427792" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="0 6.975476839237056 0" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="6.975476839237056"></line>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: No, the two Actions are independant so they will not block each other.
My guess, the click causes you to navigate to a different page/changes the page and that is why the second attempt fails. If you run the code and inspect the website (F12 developer tools) is the element you are looking for still the same?
Please share the html code of the relevant element before the first action & when it fails the second time.

Comment: @TacoVerhagen I added the HTML of the Elements. The program does not (intentionally) navigate to another page or change it.

Comment: I would use explicit waits instead. I've always had problems with implicit waits.